# how can i send system file to another api using @FeginClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, feign, kaizala

I have to send System file to my other service using `@FeignClient`.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "v1/media")
@Headers({"Content-Type: multipart/form-data"})
void uploadMedia(@RequestHeader("refreshToken") String refreshToken, @RequestPart File FileName);
```

Error:

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "message":"No file to upload!", 
>         "errorCode":"InvalidParameters", 
>         "errorCategoryKey":"InvalidParametersException"
>     }
> ]
> ```

Comment: Could you please post the error?

Comment: I am getting  [{"message":"No file to upload!","errorCode":"InvalidParameters","errorCategoryKey":"InvalidParametersException"}]
 It's Kaizala media upload rest point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used the RestTemplate for the upload the Image and it's working.

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    headers.set("accessToken", accessToken);
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    body.add("file", new FileSystemResource(new File("File.png")));
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
    String serverUrl = "/v1/media";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<MediaResource> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(serverUrl, requestEntity, MediaResource.class);
    System.out.println("Response code: " + response);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is this:
You set content-type "multipart/form-data", but your argument's type is File. Try to set "MultipartFile" for your argument's type and repeat, please.

Answer (score 0):

I think most popular way the file upload via MultipartFile

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload" method = RequestMethod.POST)
void uploadMedia(@RequestHeader("refreshToken") String refreshToken, @RequestPart MultipartFile file)
```